# Export a data frame to different CSVs with 1000 lines each

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with about 1 million rows and 45 columns.

For an upload program we have to split it now because the system only manages 1000 per run. It's fully automated - but we can't change it. At the end I need an export of several CSV.

But I don't know how to solve this best in Python. First to split the Data Frame in several Data Frames or direct export to CSV?

Important is the following.

Each CSV needs the same 1st line which is the 1st line in the data frame. After that there should be 1000 positions. The file contains however no running counter, ID or other.

Comment: Look at `Dask`. It has a its own wrapper for `pandas.DataFrame`, which allows you to keep the large file on your disk, and while doing calculations, `Dask` will automatically load the data in smaller chunks. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: First, is the dataframe in memory or already in a CSV file? And then is your dataframe simple enough to have exactly one line per row in CSV?

Comment: Hello Serge

Basic is a large CSV file we get from a legacy system. Problem is that we just have archived csv file and now this data should be migrated to a new system and we just can work with CSV for import and just by 1000 (horrible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
#Load your CSV
df = pd.read_csv("Your-file.csv") #Load the file

#Write out the lines you need with a while
i = 0
j = 1000
while j < len(equzi):
    equzi[i:j].to_csv('output'+str(j)+'.csv', index=False, sep=";")
    i = j + 1
    j += 1000
```

Because you said that the first line should be the same and in my understanding is this the header.

Comment: I think equzi is meant to be the dataframe, df.

Comment: The while loop will stop before all data is written.  As coded, if there are 1,200 rows, on the first loop j is 1000, the second loop never gets written as j is 2000 and greater than the length of the dataframe.  200 lines are never written to the file.  

To ensure the last chunk of data is written the end point should be increased by J.  The code is: while j < len(equzi) + 1000:

Comment: sep=";" is actually sep="," for comma separated values, CSV, files,

Answer (score 1):

Only my opinion, but I would just export the full dataframe into a large CSV file. Because splitting a text file (what a csv file is) in Python is trivial and will only be limited by the disk speed.

Python code could look like:

```
def split(infile, outtemplate, maxlines, first=0):
    """Splits an input file in chunks of size maxlines.
    The initial line will be repeated in each of the output files.
    Params:
        infile:      path of the input file
        outtemplate: template for the paths of the output file; will use format to insert
                       the chunk number
        maxlines:    maximim number of lines per chunk
        first:       number of the first output file
    """
    with open(infile, "rb") as fdin:  # use binary to not worry for encoding
        header_line = next(fdin)      # store the initial line 
        fdout = None
        for line in fdin:
            if fdout is None:         # if no output file create one 
                numlig = 0
                fdout = fopen(template.format(first), "wb")
                fdout.write(header)   # do not forget the header
            fdout.write(line)
            numlig += 1
            if numlig >= maxlines:    # limited to maxlines
                fdout.close()
                fdout = None          # prepare for next chunk
                first += 1
    fdout.close()                     # close the current output file
```

It could be used as:

```
split("/path/to/initial.csv", "/path/to/resul_{}.csv", 1000)
```

Beware: this assumes exactly one line per row. Do not use if some fields can contain newlines, but use the csv module.

Beware(2): with this code the resulting files will be 1001 lines long: the header line followed with 1000 data lines. Use `split(..., ..., 999)` to have files exactly 1000 lines long.

Beware(3) : untested code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the following:

```
# Create an iterator with pandas dataframes of size 1000
chunks= pd.read_csv(filename, .., chunksize=1000)

# Iterate over it
for i, df in enumerate(chunks):

    # Do whatever

    # Write i-th dataframe
    df.to_csv(f'destination_name_{i}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']).to_csv('bigfile.csv', index=False)
chunks = pd.read_csv('bigfile.csv', chunksize=10, iterator=False)
for n, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk.to_csv(f'file_{n}', index=False, header=True)
```